# excel - if cell contains item set another cell to todays date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

What I am trying to achieve is when a cell contains a string value, then I want an adjacent cell to equal todays date:

for example

```
Order Number      Date
     1          05-11-2014
     2          05-11-2014
                no item
     3          05-11-2014
```

so when there is an order number, I want excel to do `=TODAY()`, or display `"no item"`

the query will look something like this however im not sure on the 2 parameters to include after search

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"cell has no value","cell has value"},B13))),"no item",TODAY())
```

thanks for any help with this guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the formula is in cell B2 and the order number is in A2:

```
=if(isnumber(A2),TODAY(),"no item")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that every time the worksheet is updated the "TODAY()" will be updated. So, today it would have today's date, tomorrow it would have tomorrows date, etc. etc.

Comment: yes I know about the TODAY() Method... thankyou for your help, me over complicating things

Comment: what happens if i want isnumber and istext to be checked?

Comment: Assuming that you want TODAY() in the date column if either text or a number is found in the order number column, you can do: `=if(or(isnumber(A2),istext(A2)),TODAY(),"no item")`